# A happy Oli♦ day!

Tags: discussion, moderators, fun

Today is November 11, so that means...

### Oli♦ day!

We'd just like to congratulate our well-known moderator, author of [thepcspy](http://thepcspy.com/), and second-highest user by reputation here on a happy birthday.

Many of us have changed our gravatars to be Oli♦:

[image]

and [last year, it was even better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx5fo.png).

If you browse the [user list](https://askubuntu.com/users), you can see all of the green faces symbolizing this happy day.

So, let's wish Oli a happy birthday, and the best of luck in thepcspy, here on Ask Ubuntu, the rest of Stack Exchange, and in life!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm ever so confused… I thought my birthday was in August…

Or has my account become more than the Oli behind it, like Jorgebot?

Comment: Who? What? Where? [Has seizure] BTW, want me to close as too localized?

Comment: I didn't start the Birthday rumour, I just continued the oli day from last year. :P

Comment: Welcome to the cult of personality!

Comment: My birthday is in september :p

Comment: See? I *thought* that last year's Oli day was celebrated not because of a birthday but because Oli became an Ubuntu member. *I'm always glad to find out that my memory isn't failing me.*

Comment: AHA! Another bot! which basically means Jorge is a Borg (Star Trek) and has infected our beloved Oli. Oli we will miss you (Taking out the big guns). It's Borg Hunting Time!!

Answer (score 17):

P.S. You are hereby assigned the right to make small or minor modifications to the original image as I have done here:

[image]

Yeah, enough said.