# Happy Oli♦ Day 2016!

Tags: discussion, fun

In case you are wondering what this is all about, I'll direct you to this related question: [A happy Oli♦ day!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5370/a-happy-oli-day)

Basically, we are celebrating our beloved moderator [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli). It's not his birthday, as since rumors suggest, but rather the anniversary of his becoming an Ubuntu member. Or to put it another way, it's an excuse to have cake and party. Whatever works.

So, what do we do here to celebrate? I'm glad you asked! (You did ask, right?) It has become tradition to replace your gravatar with [that of Oli's](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f0af40756420859b5b63cbceb6d30505?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG) for the duration of the day. You can see that I have done this.

tl;dr — happy Oli♦ Day!

Comment: Congratulations @oli ! :)

Comment: While I was middle of the post I got confused looking at the gravatar.

Comment: Congratulations! @Oli

Comment: @Anwar it looked as if Oli had set a reaeaeaeally interesting bounty on something :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I jumped by just reading the bounty word in my notification this time :)

Comment: +1 for good excuse to buy a cake today. But what /where is a gravatar?